# C# Directory.GetDirectories Output to string

Tags: c#, directory, criteria, system.diagnostics, process.start

`string[] directory = Directory.GetDirectories(path, Criteria)`

Using the above and `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory)` I can open up multiple directory that meet certain Criteria - the criteria being the name of the folder in a directory.

How do I take the output of the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory)` and convert to a string, rather than open the directory?

All the subfolders within the directories that would open, have the same folder structure, so I would like to navigate to specific subfolders within these directories; the only way I can think of doing that, is by redirecting the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory)` output to a string, and adding the rest of folder path such as `@'\Photos'` to the output string and then using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newPath);` on this new folder path.

If anyone has a better way of doing it I'm all ears. My full code is below:

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\";
string criteria = "*" + textBox1.Text + "*";

string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path, criteria);
foreach (string directory in dir)
      {
          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory);
      }
```

Comment: What is the output of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directory)`?

Comment: The output of Process.Start(directory) is a process. How exactly would you want to convert this to a string?

Comment: Why don't you add the extra path information _before_ you call `Process.Start`? e.g. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(directory, "Photos"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of folders within a folder, you can use the same method `Directory.GetDirectories()`

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\";
string criteria = "*" + textBox1.Text + "*";

string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path, criteria);
foreach (string directory in dir)
{
    string newCriteria = "Photos";
    string[] subDir = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, newCriteria);
    foreach (string subDirectory in subDir)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(subDirectory);
    }
}
```

Comment: one line helped me thanks, and for a more complete solution based on your principles can be officially found at [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree) to go through a directory recursively with error catching. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a directory is an hierarchy of zero, one or more directories you'll need to create a recursive method, that is method that calls it self until there no more directories found in a  directory. The condition when to stop is the most important part of a recursive call...

You could change your code as follows by adding this method:

```
public string GetDirs(string path, string criteria)
{
      // store all directory names
      var allDirs = new StringBuilder();
      string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path, criteria);
      foreach (string directory in dir)
      {
          allDirs.AppendFormat("{0}\r\n", directory);
          // recursively call GetDirs again
          var subdirs = GetDirs(Path.Combine(path,directory), criteria);
          // store the subdirectory names
          allDirs.Append(subdirs);
      }
      // no more subdirs?
      if (dir.Length == 0) {
         // maybe show that dir?
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
      }
      return allDirs.ToString();
}
```

And then you call that method from the code you had (I assume you have a textBox2 to show the result of GetDirs as well):

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\";
string criteria = "*" + textBox1.Text + "*";

var dirs = GetDirs(path, criteria);
// assume you want to show those dirs
// add it to a textbox...
textBox2.Text = dirs;
```

That is all. Now you can have a lot of fun with this if you run `GetDirs` with `"C:\"` and `""` ....